# В приложении при клике на кнопку назад перекидывает назад на активность, повторный клик обновляет активность, а не уничтожает активность

Tags: android, activity

Возможно, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, что при клике на телефоне по кнопке "назад" или back уничтожается активность и вы попадаете на предыдущую активность, и должно работать таким образом что при клике на кнопку назад, должно перекидывать назад до тех пор, пока приложение не закроется. У нас же перекидывает только на одну активность назад, а потом сколько бы раз мы не кликали на кнопку назад, просто обновляется активность и все, может быть посоветуете куда копать, что может влиять на стек активностей или на запрет destroя активностей или вообще что это может быть.

Вот пример активити, которая также просто обновляется при клике на кнопку назад, не уничтожается, а просто она же сама появляется, какая то петля и все.

Пробовал добавлять onBackPressed() и finish() пробовал, ничто из этого не уничтожает активити.

```
public class FavoriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;
    Cursor cursor;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_index:
                    go_main();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_catalog:
                    go_catalog();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_favorite:
                    go_favorite();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_cart:
                    go_cart();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    go_profile();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_favorite);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        getCountFavorite(navigation);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

        int tblID = 0;

        int urlPictIndex = 0;
        int idIndex = 0;
        int quantityIndex = 0;
        int nameIndex = 0;
        int priceIndex = 0;
        int priceOldIndex = 0;
        int articleIndex = 0;
        int sizeIndex = 0;
        int detail_page_url = 0;

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //Cursor cursor = database.query("cart", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        //cursor.moveToNext();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM favorites";
        cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        ScrollView cart_root_ll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.cart_root_sv);
        ScrollView cart_root_ll_empty = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.cart_root_sv_empty);
        ScrollView cart_root_sv_order_ok = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.cart_root_sv_order_ok);

        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            cart_root_sv_order_ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cart_root_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cart_root_ll_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            cart_root_sv_order_ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cart_root_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cart_root_ll_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final LinearLayout mparent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cartBaseContainer);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //Integer totalPrice = 0;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                tblID = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");

                urlPictIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("urlPict");
                idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
                quantityIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("quantity");
                nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
                priceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("price");
                priceOldIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("priceOld");
                articleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("article");
                sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("size");
                detail_page_url = cursor.getColumnIndex("detail_page_url");

                final View myview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_cart, null, false);
                TextView tv_inflater_art = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_art);
                TextView tv_inflater_name = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_name);
                TextView tv_inflater_quantity = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_quantity);
                TextView tv_inflater_price = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_price);
                ImageView iv_inflater_urlPict = (ImageView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_img);

                tv_inflater_art.setText(cursor.getString(articleIndex));
                tv_inflater_name.setText(cursor.getString(nameIndex));
                tv_inflater_quantity.setText(cursor.getString(quantityIndex) + " шт");

                tv_inflater_price.setText(String.format(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, "%,d", cursor.getInt(priceIndex)) + " P");

                final String detailPageURL = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("detail_page_url"));
                myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(FavoriteActivity.this, CatalogElementActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("elementPageURL",detailPageURL);
                        FavoriteActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                String size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);

                TextView tv_inflater_size = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_size);
                tv_inflater_size.setText(size);

                if (size.length() == 0) {
                    LinearLayout tv_s1 = (LinearLayout) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_size_root);
                    tv_s1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                Picasso
                        .get()
                        .load("https://website.ru" + cursor.getString(urlPictIndex))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.preloader)
                        .into(iv_inflater_urlPict);

                ImageView tv_inflater_cart_delete_item = (ImageView) myview.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cart_delete_item);

                final int finalTblID = cursor.getInt(tblID);
                tv_inflater_cart_delete_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    DBHelper dbHelper2;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dbHelper2 = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        final SQLiteDatabase database2 = dbHelper2.getWritableDatabase();

                        String queryD = "DELETE FROM favorites WHERE _id = " + String.valueOf(finalTblID);
                        database2.execSQL(queryD);
                        database2.close();

                        myview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        getCountFavorite(navigation);
                    }
                });

                mparent.addView(myview);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    private void getCountFavorite(BottomNavigationView navigation) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM favorites;";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int menuItemId = navigation.getMenu().getItem(2).getItemId();
        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = navigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId);

        String queryCart = "SELECT count(*) FROM cart;";
        Cursor cursorCart = database.rawQuery(queryCart, null);
        cursorCart.moveToFirst();

        int menuItemIdCart = navigation.getMenu().getItem(3).getItemId();
        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawableCart = navigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemIdCart);

        if(cursorCart.getInt(0) > 0) {
            badgeDrawableCart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8C1818"));
            badgeDrawableCart.setNumber(cursorCart.getInt(0));
            badgeDrawableCart.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            badgeDrawableCart.setVisible(false);
        }

        if(cursor.getInt(0) > 0) {
            badgeDrawable.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8C1818"));
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(cursor.getInt(0));
            badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }


    public void go_catalog() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatalogSectionsActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void go_catalog(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatalogSectionsActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void go_main() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void go_favorite() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FavoriteActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void go_cart() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void go_profile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Без кода понять в чем проблема невозможно. Смотрите не переопределен ли метод onBackPressed или onDestroy и не является ли приложение лаунчером(маловероятно). Еще в редких случаях BroadcastReceiver может цеплять кнопки назад/домой/меню. Лучше переназначить onBackPressed и посмотреть вызывается ли он.

Comment: Я приложил код одной из activity , которая также уходит в петлю при клике на кнопку назад, то есть она не уничтожается, просто обновляется и все. Пробовал добавлять onBackPressed, и добавлял finish() ничего не помогает, все равно просто релоад активити и все тут.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать код из onResume. Как я понял у вас создается активность FavoriteActivity.onCreate, потом еще одна Х.onCreate, вы закрываете Х.finish и автоматом вызывается FavoriteActivity.onResume где прописано setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_favorite) = go_favorite() = FavoriteActivity.onCreate

Comment: @BuenasDias, дам вам несколько советов как новичку: 1) посмотрите что такое `Logcat`, сделайте на все методы логирование, смотрите на жизненный цикл приложения в `logcat` - так вы научитесь понимать какой код нужно добавлять в `onCreate`, а какой в `onResume`. 2) Динамическое создание списка конечно полезно освоить, но, лучше сразу изучить что такое `RecyclerView`, и как с ним работать. Теперь о вашем вопросе: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, FavoriteActivity.class) ` зачем вам переход из `FavoriteActivity.class` в `FavoriteActivity.class` ?

Comment: @Tiarait , спасибо! Получилось, вопрос решен!

Comment: @AndreyMihalev , и вам спасибо, я понял зачем это, спросив у программиста который писал этот код))) , он хотел чтобы кнопка не отрабатывала в холостую. И вашими советами я воспользуюсь, спасибо!